# Parse's API says to use a curl request. I want to use AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am creating an object using Parse's API and am confused on how and where to use it in my Javascript code.

**Parse API:**
https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects-creating

This is an *example* of how to create an object stated in Parse's API:

```
 curl -X POST \
 -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: bLAj1fl7B77TZYo1zv9vIAiUgC19RXgpzsFZeVgM" \
 -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: PPrIdiqZXMHT1JwveI2AdhsAhGpx7WjXfvYTSYXh" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
 https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

I'm trying to use AJAX to send a POST request which appends some text to a list item.

**My Javascript code:**

```
  button.click(function(){      // Submitting text from a textbox       
    $.ajax({
      url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/<className>',  // What is className?
      type: 'POST',
      data:  text.val(),        // Text the user inputted in a textbox
      error: function (data) { 
       console.log('error');
      }, 
      success: function (data) {
           $('ul').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
      }
    });
  });
```

How and where would I use the curl request like the example in my code? Also, I do not know what Parse means by 'className' in the url key. If the ul's class name that I wanted the text to appear in was called "message" then would url key in my AJAX request be 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Messages'?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @epascarello What do you when you imply the same origin policy? Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: @leggooo for security reasons, it is impossible in JavaScript to make an AJAX request to a different domain

Comment: @DuncanNZ, not 100% true if the site/browser supports CORS

Answer (score 3):

You need to use something like

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject',
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    headers : {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id' : 'bLAj1fl7B77TZYo1zv9vIAiUgC19RXgpzsFZeVgM',
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key' : 'PPrIdiqZXMHT1JwveI2AdhsAhGpx7WjXfvYTSYXh'
    },
    data : JSON.stringify({
                key : 'value: ' + new Date().getTime()
            }),
    error : function(data) {
        console.log('error');
    },
    success : function(data) {
        console.log('success', data)
        $('ul').append('<li>' + JSON.stringify(data) + '</li>');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U4d72/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am having trouble deciding what to put for <className>? Any thoughts?

Comment: you can give any name you want like `TestObject`

Comment: I see the site allows CORS, means it will only work with browsers that support it.

Comment: I don't understand this part:   

`data : JSON.stringify({
      key : 'value: ' + new Date().getTime()
}),`

Comment: @epascarello Why would you use .stringify()?

Comment: @Arun P Johny Why would you use .stringify()?

Comment: the site accepts data as request payload rather than request parameter (`contentType : 'application/json'`), so we need to pass the data as string to jquery otherwise jquery will sent the data as parameter

Comment: Took me ages to figure this out, but after finding this post everything became clear.Wish Parse had a simple example on there site. I was so stuck on Curl / Python ... it worked in the Terminal but to get to what I got below took some thinking.